# Quicksight an error has been thrown from the AWS Athena client. Insufficient Lake Formation permission(s) on <table>

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, amazon-quicksight, aws-lake-formation

My Quicksight is configured with a custom IAM role, which `Quicksight` assumes every time it refreshes Quicksight datasets. Those datasets are connected to an Athena Data Source.

Before applying `LakeFormation` permissions all has been working as expected. The Quicksight role has then been granted all necessary permissions in Lake Formation. When I assume that role(`aws sts`) in a script, access works as expected and I can see the data, but in Quicksight dataset refreshes there is an ongoing exception:

```bash
[Simba][AthenaJDBC](100071) An error has been thrown from the AWS Athena client. Insufficient Lake Formation permission(s) on <table_name> (Service: AWSGlue; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; ...
```

In Cloudtrail, when comparing the two approaches(`GetTable` event), in the assume-role approach the only difference is that it is `invokedBy: athena.amazonaws.com` , while from QS: `quicksight.amazonaws.com`.

Also, from the QS Cloudtrail this is the only info I get:

```json
 "errorCode": "AccessDenied",
 "errorMessage": "An unknown error occurred",
 "additionalEventData": {
        "LakeFormationTrustedCallerInvocation": "true"
  },
```

The quicksight IAM role:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutBucketPublicAccessBlock",
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:CreateBucket",
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<s3_bucket_results>/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<s3_bucket_results>"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "athena:StopQueryExecution",
                "athena:StartQueryExecution",
                "athena:RunQuery",
                "athena:ListWorkGroups",
                "athena:ListTableMetadata",
                "athena:ListQueryExecutions",
                "athena:ListEngineVersions",
                "athena:ListDatabases",
                "athena:ListDataCatalogs",
                "athena:GetWorkGroup",
                "athena:GetTables",
                "athena:GetTableMetadata",
                "athena:GetTable",
                "athena:GetQueryResultsStream",
                "athena:GetQueryResults",
                "athena:GetQueryExecutions",
                "athena:GetQueryExecution",
                "athena:GetNamespaces",
                "athena:GetNamespace",
                "athena:GetExecutionEngines",
                "athena:GetExecutionEngine",
                "athena:GetDatabase",
                "athena:GetDataCatalog",
                "athena:GetCatalogs",
                "athena:CancelQueryExecution",
                "athena:BatchGetQueryExecution"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "glue:UpdateTable",
                "glue:UpdatePartition",
                "glue:UpdateDatabase",
                "glue:GetTables",
                "glue:GetTable",
                "glue:GetPartitions",
                "glue:GetPartition",
                "glue:GetDatabases",
                "glue:GetDatabase",
                "glue:CreateTable",
                "glue:CreatePartition",
                "glue:CreateDatabase",
                "glue:BatchGetPartition",
                "glue:BatchCreatePartition"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "lakeformation:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<s3_bucket>/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<s3_bucket>",
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Trust relationship for IAM role:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "quicksight.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

Quicksight is configured in `eu-west-2`. Lakeformation, S3, Glue and Athena are also configured in `eu-west-2`.

Also, I have tried to configure individual Quicksight users access, by adding their Quicksight ARNs in Lake formation, by following this AWS Guide [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/enable-fine-grained-permissions-for-amazon-quicksight-authors-in-aws-lake-formation/). It works. But I cannot understand why this does not work with Quicksight's IAM role. Does anyone have any suggestions here as to how further debug or fix?

Comment: What is the Quicksight Datasource, an Athena / Glue Table? How does your IAM role look like?

Comment: @RobertKossendey Data source is an Athena Data source, Quicksight datasets are custom SQL queries using that Athena data source. IAM policy for role added , see above

Comment: Could you also provide the Trust Relationship of the role?

Comment: Have you perhaps tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/65602261?

Comment: Yes I have given all permissions to Lakeformation on this IAM role. Also if you read my question carefully: "When I assume that role(aws sts) in a script, access works as expected and I can see the data". This role access works outside Quicksight, but not when called from inside Quicksight.

Comment: @and_apo Add athena.amazonaws.com to the list of principals in your trust policy - does that work? (just turn ‘Service’ into ‘an array of strings’)

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Already tried that, also does not work , same exception occurs. Also this is part of the Cloud trail event:

    `"eventSource": "glue.amazonaws.com",
    "eventName": "GetTable",
    "awsRegion": "eu-west-2",
    "sourceIPAddress": "quicksight.amazonaws.com",
    "userAgent": "quicksight.amazonaws.com",
    "errorCode": "AccessDenied",
    "errorMessage": "An unknown error occurred",`

Comment: Try adding glue.amazonaws.com to the services list instead

Comment: Unfortunately the same exception occurs, also tried `lakeformation.amazonaws.com`